# Problem with OpenSSL on Catalina using node.js

Tags: node.js, openssl, macos-catalina

I'm not really sure if this is a problem with MacOS Catalina, OpenSSL or Node, but I recently discovered that I can't request certain URLs using node.js.

This is the code which triggers the error:

```
  request({
    method: 'GET',
    uri: 'sample url goes here',
    json: true,
    auth: {
      user: 'some username',
      pass: 'some password',
      sendImmediately: false
    }
  }, (error, response, body) => // ...
```

When using `request` on node version 8.11.3, this is the error I get:

> request: { Error: write EPROTO 4483825088:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:827:
>
> at _errnoException (util.js:992:11)
>       at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:864:14) code: 'EPROTO', errno: 'EPROTO', syscall: 'write' } }

The error is slightly different when using node 10.15.3:

> { Error: write EPROTO 4545691072:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:252:
>
> at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:779:14) errno: 'EPROTO', code: 'EPROTO', syscall: 'write' } }

So in the first call the error seems to be **unknown protocol** and **wrong version number** in the second.

I've googled around but the error seems pretty generic and not specifically related to node.js, but I'm not getting this error when using CURL. I am however, getting an SSL error when I'm using Insomnia (a REST client which I think uses node in the background). The logs in Insomnia give me this:

```
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* WARNING: disabling hostname validation also disables SNI.
* Server aborted the SSL handshake
* Closing connection 10
```

I'm guessing this could have to do with Catalina since I recently upgraded. I also updated brew packages after upgrading, so that could also be the problem.

What I've tried so far is to default to OpenSSL from Homebrew (`export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"`) because I read that Catalina was using libressl and I figured that might've been the problem. That didn't change anything though.

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: What's the exact NodeJS code you're running?

Comment: I've added it to the question. I've tried with 8.11.3 and 10.15.3. UPDATE: Oh, my bad, you asked for code not version.. hold on

Comment: Not the version of NodeJS. Your code that's running inside of NodeJS.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Added code sample

Comment: That's not reproducible. Please use a real URL that we can hit too. If your URL is sensitive, then try to reproduce it with https://google.com or something.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica fair enough, I think I found related issues.. Will close soon